# Session resets after every app restart in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express

Whenever I make changes to my app, nodemon restarts the whole app, but every time this happens, my session gets destroyed. This is getting annoying since I have to sign in every time I make changes to my app. How do I avoid this from happening?

I'm using cookie based sessions since I only store the userid. My setup looks like this (in coffeescript):

```
app.use express.cookieParser()
app.use express.session
  secret: 'mysecretkey'
app.use express.csrf()
```

And I save my session by doing this:

```
req.session.userid = user._id.toHexString() # it's a mongoDB ObjectID
req.session.save()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default expresssJS uses in-memory storage for sessions, so when your app is reset so are the in-memory session.

Since you are using mongoDB I would recommend using mongoDB for your session storage, or redis (which I haven't tried with node).

You can see this question on how to set up session support with express and mongo:

[How to store session values with Node.js and mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364253/how-to-store-session-values-with-node-js-and-mongodb)

Comment: aw crap. why isn't that said in the guide? i assumed it was cookie based. thanks!

Comment: which mongodb-based session should i use? https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo or https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb? i can't tell a difference.

Comment: I'm using connect-mongo and have had no problems. It's fairly straightforward to plug-in the other if you encounter something you don't like about one of them :)